# Google App Engine Model Property Update

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-datastore

When I try to update my model from:

```
class Submissions(ndb.Model):                                                                
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

to:

```
class Submissions(ndb.Model):                                                                
     title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
     content = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
     dummy = ndb.IntegerProperty(default = 0)
     created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

new Submissions entities which I create do not appear to have the new property "dummy". When I look in SDK Console->Datastore Viewer, the new entities still only have properties "title", "content" and "created".

Can anyone suggest why this is happening? I am very confused!

Comment: do they have the properties when you examine them in the code? If so, that's working and the datastore viewer is out of date for whatever reason. It's just a bonus feature, don't worry too much if your application works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know what the problem was, but when I cloned the content into a new repository, everything was working fine!